# "Invalid filename extension" and "Type is not known" when I run `sudo apt-get ...` commands

Tags: apt, software-sources

```
brownguy@brownguy:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Error!
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Type 'brownguy@brownguy:~$' is not known on line 1 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/libdvdcss.list
E: The list of sources could not be read.
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'some-ppa.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

Answer (score 0):

This error message is occurring because you have invalid PPA entries in your sources.list.d.  To be able to install updates, edit the appropriate file and remove the entries listed in the error messages.

Once updated, you can follow up by finding the correct PPA name information for whatever that PPA was intended to provide, and reenter it, either with `sudo apt-add-repository [PPA]`, with the sources editor built into a package manager like Synaptic, or by directly editing the same file you edited to correct the error.

Answer (score 0):

1. The folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` contains PPA which have extension as either `.list.save` or `.list`. But a PPA name some-ppa saved with extension `.list.save.2`. I think you have manually added to this folder. Use

   ```
    sudo apt-add-repository
   ```
2. The file should have read permission '-rw-r--r--'. Check for the same via `ls -ltr  /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`
3. It is untrusted PPA source which is not updated since 185 weeks ago. Make sure you want to install this.

   [https://launchpad.net/~jdew](https://launchpad.net/%7Ejdew)